# GWT - Code Splitting - How can GWT know which data load first time?

Tags: gwt

Im curios about this. I have for example this code :

```
button_article.addClickListener(new ClickListener(){
    public void onClick(Widget w) {
        GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() {
            public void onFailure(Throwable reason) {
                // somethings
            }

            public void onSuccess() {
                content.clear();
                content.designArticles();
            }
        });
    }
});

public final void designArticles() {
    this.add(new ProfileArticles(this.rpcService, this));
}
```

I see that until i click on button_article, the elements on ProfileArticles() (that is a FlowPanel) arent loaded when i start the application. So, how can GWT know that element on that class shouldnt loaded when the application start? It check each methods under GWT.runAsync() and their correspondents Class?

I also see that when i leave that "context" they arent released (in fact, if i change context and i return there, when i click again on that method it doesnt call the server. So it use the previous loaded code). Is it right? :)

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GWT compiler analyzes the flow of your program to figure out what chunks it can load later.  If you want to visually understand what it's done, check out http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport.html .

Once code is loaded, most of it can be cached, so even if the user navigates off the page and then back to yours, the code will not need to be reloaded.